# Adding Microsoft files to a MySQL database using html 5 and PHP, when I retrieve the files I get a message "Word found unreadable content in

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a web form to add files to a database, and it works, but all of the Microsoft office file formatted files give error messages, when the files are opened.

Adding Microsoft files to a MySQL database using html 5 and php, when I retrieve the files I get a message "Word found unreadable content in test_file.docx. Do you want to recover the contents of this document?" with a Yes button and a No button, if I click Yes, I get my file.  A similar situation happens with all of the Office format files, but not with PDF files, or image files, or txt files.

Does anyone have experience with this, and have a solution?

I have played with the mime file types, but even with mime type for docx "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" I still get the message when I try to open the Office files.
And yes, I have the other mime types setup also.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Edit your question** and show the code that generates/downloads the MS file for Word. Are you allowing Word to directly access the DB or are you downloading the file and then trying to open it in Word?

Comment: Show the code where you're inserting the data. There's a high probability that you're mangling it on insert and/or retrieval.

Comment: Where to see the bug if you are not showing us the code?

Comment: The code works, the message is seen when I open the document.  So Microsoft Word shows the message.  But also each of the Microsoft office documents have a message, slightly different.

Comment: I don't think the code is the issue.  My files load from my form, and I can call my files from the database, they download properly, the issue is from Microsoft, although the files will load, they first open with a message. For Word the message is "Word found unreadable content in "the file name.docx" Do you want to recover the contents of this document? If you trust the source of this document, click Yes." But I get slightly different messages from xlsx files and pptx files, but they all open the files and the content is good.  I think there is some changes in the mime content stored in MySQL

Comment: The code is long, but the core of it is this:

Comment: $myfileStuff = (int)$_GET['theIDgiven'];
$myPolicy = $_GET['policyInfo'];
 $myStuff = $myfileStuff;
if (isset($_POST["add_"])){
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if ((!empty($_FILES['file_data'])) && (($_FILES['file_data']['size']) > 0)) {
 $ext = strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file_data']['name'])));
 $allowed = array("pdf","txt","docx","pptx","xlsx");
if( ! in_array($ext, $allowed)) {echo 'Sorry this file type is not allowed!';}
else {
$date_ = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["date_"]);
$fileData = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['file_data']['tmp_name']));

Comment: part 2$fileName = $_FILES['file_data']['name'];
$fileinfo = $_FILES['file_data']['type'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file_data']['type'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file_data']['size'];
$query2 = "UPDATE `dbname`.`table` SET date = '$date_', file_data = '$fileData', file_name = '$fileName', file_mime = '$fileType', file_size = '$fileSize' WHERE id = '$myStuff';";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
if ($result2){
include("../includes/headers.php");
}

Comment: Sorry I had to make that in 2 parts, but I don't think my code is an issue, I can load any file type I want, and the only ones that have issues are in the Office format

Comment: It looks like I have the answer, it is either of two things, I added another header line  header("Content-length: $theSize");  or it was the removal of the closing php file line ?>  I tried each later, but it still seems to work, so thanks for all of your help, but I have this working now.   THANK YOU!!!